# Use ... to pass index to functions

Tags: r

For the following code and output.

```
ind <- function(x, ..., drop=T) { x[...,,drop=drop]}
indd <- function(x, ..., drop=T) { ind(x, ..., drop=drop)}
x=array(1:24,1:4)
ind(x,,1,)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    7   13   19
## [2,]    3    9   15   21
## [3,]    5   11   17   23
indd(x,,,1,)
## Error in ind(x, ..., drop = drop) : argument is missing, with no default.
```

Why the ... works for the function "ind" but not work for the function "indd"?

When I debug the function "ind" directly (`ind(x,,1,)`), I got

```
match.call(expand.dots=FALSE)
## ind(x = x, ... = list(, 1, ))
substitute(list(...))
## list(, 1, )
```

However, if the debugging is triggered by "indd" (`indd(x,,1,)`), I got

```
match.call(expand.dots=FALSE)
## ind(x = x, ... = list(..1, 1, ..3), drop = drop)
substitute(list(...))
## list(, 1, )
```

I don't understand why `match.call` gives different results under the two cases but `substitute(list(...))` gives the same result.

How to make the function "indd" work just the same as the function "ind" by calling it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am converting a S-Plus program to an R program. The code works in S-Plus but not in R. I am very curious about the reason why it doesn't work in R.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why `match.call` gives different results under the two cases.

But I find a trick to fix the function "indd".

```
indd <- function(x, ..., drop=T)
{ 
  car = as.character(match.call(expand.dots=FALSE)$...)
  eval(parse(text=paste("ind(x,", paste(car, ",", collapse=""), "drop=drop)")))
}
```